# javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException using Spring ConstraintValidator for an enumeration

Tags: java, validation, spring-boot, spring-validator

I have implemented a ConstraintValidator in order to valide a DTO that contains an enumeration. I followed [this Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation-spring-constraints) for that.

This is the custom annotation to be applied to the enum field:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR,
    ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = EnumValidator.class)
public @interface ValidEnum {

  String message() default "{com.test.validation.constraints.ValidEnum}";

  Class<?>[] groups() default {};

  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

  Class<? extends Enum<?>> target();

}
```

The `EnumValidator` looks like this:

```
public class EnumValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidEnum,String> {

      private Set<String> enumValues;

      @Override
      public void initialize(ValidEnum targetEnum) {
          Class<? extends Enum> enumSelected = targetEnum.targetClassType();
          enumValues = (Set<String>) EnumSet.allOf(enumSelected).stream()
              .map(e -> ((Enum<? extends Enum<?>>) e).name()).collect(Collectors
                  .toSet());
      }

      @Override
      public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
          return enumValues.contains(value);
      }
  }
```

This is the enum:

```
public enum Gender {
  MALE,FEMALE;
}
```

This is the DTO to validate:

```
public final class UserDTO{

  @ValidEnum(target = Gender.class)
  private Gender gender;

  @NotEmpty
  @Max(100)
  private String fullName;
}
```

And the controller that is validating the field:

```
@Controller
public class RegistrationController {

  private static final String REGISTER_USER = "/register";

  private final RegistrationService registrationService;


  @PostMapping(value = REGISTER_USER)
  @Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
  public UserRegistrationResponse register(@Valid UserDTO userRegistrationRequest) {

    return registrationService.register(userRegistrationRequest);
  }

}
```

It seems that Spring is not detecting the validator, because it throws this exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; 
nested exception is javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: 

No validator could be found for constraint 'com.test.ws.web.validation.ValidEnumType' validating type 'com.test.ws.domain.model.Gender'. Check configuration for 'gender'
```

I am using Spring boot 2.0.4 which include the required dependencies for validation.

Any idea why it fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three mistakes in your code.

1. `@Max(100)` this annotation shouldn't be applied to String field! only for numeric type. If you need to specify  String size range restrictions you may use `@Size(min = 2, max = 250)` annotation.
2. You forgot `RequestBody` annotation in the controller method signature:

`register(@Valid @RequestBody UserDTO userRegistrationRequest)`

3. Enum validation consume String value from Rest API, not Enum itself. That's why you've got an error here.

I've created test project for you. Please check it here https://github.com/alex-petrov81/stackoverflow-answers/tree/master/enum-validator

Comment: I had already fixed the 2 first points because there were tiny mistakes, but the last one is whichI really forgot. It worked, thank you